# Is it possible to use additional images with Multipass?

Tags: multipass

I'd like to use multipass to set up arch, debian, and amazon linux 2 images in addition to ubuntu images; is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://multipass.run/docs/launch-command it sounds like you can run others provided they have accessible isos. `image`  is the part you want afaik

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1174933)